# Spark (scala): How to get interval of dates from dataframe into a new dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I need help to explode a dataframe in Spark (Scala language) with date interval in a new dataframe as below example.

I use Spark 2.3.2, so don't have the specific function to do it.

Original dataframe:

```
EVENT   INITIAL_DATE    END_DATE
event1  01/01/2023      04/01/2023
event2  15/02/2023      17/02/2023
```

New dataframe:

```
EVENT    DATE
event1   01/01/2023
event1   02/01/2023
event1   03/01/2023
event1   04/01/2023
event2   15/02/2023
event2   16/02/2023
event2   17/02/2023
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates a sample dataframe with your two rows of data.

```
// libraries
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

// column definition
val cols = new StructType()
  .add("event_str", "string")
  .add("start_str", "string")
  .add("end_str", "string")

// create rdd
val rows: RDD[Row] = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Row("event1", "01/01/2023", "04/01/2023"),
    Row("event2", "15/02/2023 ", "17/02/2023")
  )
)

// create df
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, cols)

// show data
df.show()
```

The output of the show statement is shown below.

[image]

The issue is that the to_date() function does not handle your format.  But we can use substring() and concat() to create the final column result as a string.  Then we can explode() a expression() using a sequence.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// str to date
val df2 = df.withColumn("start_date", to_date(concat(substring(col("start_str"), 4, 2), lit("/"), substring(col("start_str"), 1, 2), lit("/"), substring(col("start_str"), 7, 4)),"MM/dd/yyyy"))

// str to date
val df3 = df2.withColumn("end_date", to_date(concat(substring(col("end_str"), 4, 2), lit("/"), substring(col("end_str"), 1, 2), lit("/"), substring(col("end_str"), 7, 4)),"MM/dd/yyyy"))

// explode sequence
val df4 = df3.withColumn("event_date", explode(expr("sequence(start_date, end_date, interval 1 day)")))

// show result
df4.select(col("event_str"), col("event_date")).show()
```

The output below shows the designed result.

[image]

Since I do not use the scala language often, it took me a little while longer with syntax.

Comment: Thanks! But sequence function is introduced in version 2.4.0. We have versione 2.3.2 :-(

Comment: Upgrade your cluster to fix the issue.